# AndroidTest java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method cannot be called on the main application thread (on: main) Espresso

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm trying to test my custom caption view. I set caption background color in shared preferences. Than I call updateCaptionStyle() (it will update my caption view) and than I assert that background color is right.

My problem is that this assertion fails.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
 @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
 class SessionActivityTest {

     private val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences by inject(SharedPreferences::class.java)

     private val intent: Intent by lazy {
         val intent =
             Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), SessionActivity::class.java)
         intent.putExtra(Constants.SESSION_ID_KEY, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
     }

     @get:Rule
     var rule = ActivityScenarioRule<SessionActivity>(intent)


     @Test
     fun сaptionView_changeBackgroundColor() {

         rule.scenario.onActivity {
             sharedPrefs.saveCaptionViewSettings(CaptionSettingsModel(backgroundColor = R.color.caption_color_orange))
             it.updateCaptionStyle()

         }

             onView(withId(R.id.caption_view)).check { view, _ ->
                 if (view is CaptionsView) {
                     val actualBackgroundColor = view.captionsBackgroundColor
                     val expectedColor =
                         ContextCompat.getColor(
                             view.context,
                             R.color.caption_color_orange
                         )
                     assertThat(actualBackgroundColor, is(equalTo(expectedColor)))
                 }
             }
     }
 }
```

I supposed it was because onView(withId(R.id.caption_view)).check.. didn't wait until all code in rule.scenario.onActivity {} would be finished.

So I moved my `onView(withId(R.id.caption_view)).check..` in `rule.scenario.onActivity {} scope.`

But I've got a new error

```
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method cannot be called on the main application thread (on: main)
at androidx.test.internal.util.Checks.checkState(Checks.java:111)
at androidx.test.internal.util.Checks$1.checkNotMainThread(Checks.java:150)
at androidx.test.internal.util.Checks.checkNotMainThread(Checks.java:130)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.postAsynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:5)
at ...**
```

I have tried a lot of options.
Tried : runBlockingTest, runOnUiThread, @UiThreadTest, view.doOnLayout{} ...

Only this code is working. But I don't understand **WHY**?
Please help me to understand if you can explain it will be really appreciated !

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
 @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
 class SessionActivityTest {
 
     private val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences by inject(SharedPreferences::class.java)
 
     private val intent: Intent by lazy {
         val intent =
             Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), SessionActivity::class.java)
         intent.putExtra(Constants.SESSION_ID_KEY, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
     }
 
     private val testScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
 
     @get:Rule
     var rule = ActivityScenarioRule<SessionActivity>(intent)
 
 
     @Test
     fun сaptionView_changeBackgroundColor() {
 
         rule.scenario.onActivity {
             sharedPrefs.saveCaptionViewSettings(CaptionSettingsModel(backgroundColor = R.color.caption_color_orange))
             it.updateCaptionStyle()
 
         }
 
         testScope.launch {
             onView(withId(R.id.caption_view)).check { view, _ ->
                 if (view is CaptionsView) {
                     val actualBackgroundColor = view.captionsBackgroundColor
                     val expectedColor =
                         ContextCompat.getColor(
                             view.context,
                             R.color.caption_color_orange
                         )
                     assertThat(actualBackgroundColor, is(equalTo(expectedColor)))
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```